# nginx: which port received the request?

Tags: nginx, httprequest

For testing purposes, I am using nginx to listen on multiple ports when I send distributed http requests. I can see the request be received by nginx - but I need to know which of its ports actually got it. I can't see any options in the logs to flag this.

I guess an ugly alternative is to install multiple instances so their logs are separated, but there must be a better way than this...?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Anything you can access as a variable in nginx config, you can log, including non-standard http headers, etc.

The var you want to add is [$server_port](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_server_port)

```
log_format  mycustomformat  '$host $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" $server_port';
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log mycustomformat;
```

Comment: there is pitfall though when using docker... $server_port is the configured port, which may not be the actual port if you run your docker container with `-p 8000:80` for example.

Comment: I'm using $upstream_addr in my docker environment to get the address and port

Comment: the doc link for $server_port variable is unavailable, a more recent one is http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_server_port (the answer cannot be edited: "Suggested edit queue is full")